# Set Range to Omit First Row in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The code (below) combines all the columns from an active sheet converts them to one Column in a sheet named Sheet3(Masterlist).

I need the to start at row 2 when all the columns are combined. This is because row 1 has the column name.

Also, I would rather use Sheet1(Orders) not the Active Sheet.

This code is modified as suggested by Yaegz. I am now getting Next without For on Line 26:

```
Sub ToArrayAndBack()
Dim arr As Variant, lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant, lIndex As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

ReDim arr2(Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells.Count - Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)

arr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value

Set myRange = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A1:A" & _
Worksheets("Orders").Cells(Worksheets("Orders").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 2
Do While i <= myRange.Rows.Count
     For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
         For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
                arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
                lIndex = lIndex + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    i = i + i
Loop

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "MasterList" Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found Then
    Sheets.Add.Name = "MasterList"
End If

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList")
With ws
     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
     .Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
     .Rows(1).Delete
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Sheet1 is the sheet code. Orders is the sheet name.

Comment: Don't know which line you consider is line 15.  But, the Do While loop you added is incomplete.  It should be more like Do While i <= myRange.Rows.Count  (code here) then i = i + 1 and then the word Loop.

Comment: @Yaegz Line 15 is `arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to point to a specific sheet instead of the active one use:
`Application.Worksheets("name of your sheet")` instead of `ActiveSheet`

The error message is because the `do while` opens a loop and it closes with the `loop` key word something like:

```
 Do while i<10
    Your Code
    i=i+1
 Loop
```

Comment: Uh Oh, don't use this code.  His Do While Loop will create an infinite loop and will crash your excel.  Make sure you put in i = i + 1 before the word Loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code works, if you want a correct Do While loop then use the following code.  It sounds like you are trying to just initialize where your code should start.  If that is the case then a Do While loop is not the way to go.

```
arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 2
Do While i <= myRange.Rows.Count
     For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
         For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
                arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
                lIndex = lIndex + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
  i = i + i
Loop
```

Comment: I changed my code in my post to reflect your changes. I am now getting a Run-time error '9' Subscript is out of range on line 17. The code there is `Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row)`